# Azure Database for MariaDB and log_bin_trust_function_creators

Tags: azure, database, mariadb

I am trying to create a function on Azure Database for MariaDB like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
```

but I am getting the error below:

```
Error SQL (1419): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Azure Database for MySql raises the same error, but we have, on Azure Portal, an option variable "log_bin_trust_function_creators" available to change to active and pass it. MariaDB don't have it available on Azure Portal.

Is there any other solution to enable function creation in Azure Database for MariaDB?

Or is there other way to change "log_bin_trust_function_creators" variable for Azure MariaDB? I tried "SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators:=1" but raised:

```
Erro SQL (1227): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: I don't understand part of your post. Do you mean that `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is present in the Azure Portal and that you cannot change it, or that it is _not_ present?

Comment: This needs moving to dba.stackexchange.com, where it might more traction.

Comment: On Azure Database for MariaDB, log_bin_trust_function_creators exists on database but I can't change it. On Azure Database for MySql I can change it because it is available on Portal configuration.

Comment: Could I move this question to dba.stackexchange.com or I have to create new question there?